# Visual Studio 2019 csc.exe exits with code -2146232797

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I've just cloned a `.NET Core` project and I can't seem to build it. The project builds perfectly on the computer of my coworker.

The following errors appear when building:

- metadata file `filepath/filename.dll` could not be found
- `csc.exe` exited with code `-2146232797`

I've already tried deleting the bin and obj folders, reinstalling `.NET Core` SDKs, cleaning and rebuilding the project, ...

Comment: That's COR_E_FAILFAST, and there are some issues on GitHub that sound like compiler errors. Are you definitely using the exact same versions of .NET core as your coworker? The exact same versions of the dependencies, in case there's an attribute in one of those that's tripping this up? Can you solve the "metadata file not found" error - does your coworker get this error too? Do they have the missing file?

Comment: The key is in the error "metadata file filepath/filename.dll could not be found". Which *other* project is needed that causes *this* failure?

Comment: @Rup We have the same version of .NET core and the same version of the dependencies. I've added the missing file to my project but I still get the csc.exe error

Comment: @ΩmegaMan I've added the missing file from my coworker to my project and the missing file error is fixed but I still get the csc.exe error.

Comment: Do a divide and conquer approach. Remove a majority of the items and see if it builds. Once it builds then add the removed components to it one by one til failure. Or start out with a fresh solution/project and add items in until failure.

Comment: Any solutions to this problem?